# How do I verify output from an external command in a Perl unit test?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

I'm writing automated tests for an external program in Perl. I want to verify the output of its `--help` command in my test.

The output of the command is like:

```
Usage: dskrb [options]

    --help                  Help

    --list                  List all tickets

    --reset                 Clear all tickets

    --debug           <arg> Debug

    --client          <arg> Client principal, user@realm

    --password        <arg> Client password

    --client-kdc      <arg> Use this KDC in client realm.

    --cd-client       <arg> Client principal for Constrained Delegation, user@realm.

    --cd-password     <arg> Password for cd-client

    --server          <arg> Server principal, e.g. HTTP/target-server.abc.com[@realm]

    --server-kdc      <arg> Unse this server realm KDC

    --site            <arg> Site of client realm

    --login           <arg> Login Name

    --login-realm     <arg> Login Realm (must be provided with login)

    --probe           <arg> Look up Kerberos KDCs

    --overwrite       <arg> Overwrite precedence of auth methods (NTLMv1, NTLM).
```

I know how to capture the output of the external program.

How can I have this whole expected output in one variable and compare that variable with the variable capturing the output?

Comment: is it a linux command?

Comment: @ prateek :  Your question is not very clear. Update your question with some expecting output. Do you want run any Linux command and want save the output in a variable?

Comment: This is a linux based device, i am automating the some tests for it. So this output comes as I run a command, and it is stored in a variable. For that thing I have code. Now I want to verfiy this output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with Test::More and use, for example, a [here-doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).

```
use Test::More;

my $expected = <<'EXPECTED';
Usage: dskrb [options]

--help                  Help

--list                  List all tickets

--reset                 Clear all tickets

--debug           <arg> Debug

--client          <arg> Client principal, user@realm

--password        <arg> Client password

--client-kdc      <arg> Use this KDC in client realm.

--cd-client       <arg> Client principal for Constrained Delegation, user@realm.

--cd-password     <arg> Password for cd-client

--server          <arg> Server principal, e.g. HTTP/target-server.abc.com[@realm]

--server-kdc      <arg> Unse this server realm KDC

--site            <arg> Site of client realm

--login           <arg> Login Name

--login-realm     <arg> Login Realm (must be provided with login)

--probe           <arg> Look up Kerberos KDCs

--overwrite       <arg> Overwrite precedence of auth methods (NTLMv1, NTLM). 
EXPECTED

is `dskrb --help`, $expected, 'usage is displayed';

done_testing;
```

---

Note that this might not be the best test. Maybe you should just check if all arguments have some description, but not really care what that is, as changing the documentation (and usage is user-faced documentation) will hardly break functionality.